Is there a Grassmann-like relation for the structure factors (usually called $d$ and $f$) obtained for Gell-Mann matrices?
I have encountered the Gell-Mann matrices, whose commutator is expressed as:
$[\lambda_i, \lambda_j] = 2i f_{ijk} \lambda_k$
and their anticommutator as:
$\{\lambda_i, \lambda_j\} = \frac{4}{3} \delta_{ij} \lambda_0 + 2 d_{ijk} \lambda_k$
where $\lambda_0$ represents the identity matrix. Is there a relationship between the structure constants $f_{ijk}$ and $d_{ijk}$? Additionally, is there an identity for the Levi-Civita symbol, analogous to Grassmann's identity?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
